Why can't I pick location/search results on dsb.dk in Firefox?
I'm trying to use dsb.dk to search for train-tickets. Recently I haven't been able to use Firefox for this, since clicking a location in the location-search dropdown does nothing. I have used the site for years and never experienced this, and don't believe I haven changed anything in my privacy setup when the issue started.
I use the site several times a week, so it's a hassle to change to another browser just for that site.
I've tried adding dsb.dk to the cookie-blocking extemption list, disabling the built-in Firefox privacy filter, all of my privacy blocking apps and disabled Adguard; both turning off the full desktop and browser extension and also just disabling blocking for dsb.dk from the Adguard extension. The issue also persists in Private windows. Non of it has solved the issue.
I'm new to web-dev, but even after disabling all the plugins, the console is full of warnings and errors:
Cookie “engagedSessionTime” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None“ attribute to it. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite www.dsb.dk
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. www.dsb.dk
Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content. markup.js:250:53
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 jquery.validate.js
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 form-validator.js
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 modernizr.js
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 travelsearch.js
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 erhverv_tile_440x280.jpg
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 svg4everybody.min.js
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 vl.js
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 gtmBundle.js
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 app.js
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 styles.css
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 vendor.js
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 dsb-app.js
This page uses the non standard property “zoom”. Consider using calc() in the relevant property values, or using “transform” along with “transform-origin: 0 0”. www.dsb.dk
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 check-ind_440x280.jpg
Cookie “cs_test_cookie” has been rejected for invalid domain. www.dsb.dk
Cookie warnings 9
downloadable font: Glyph bbox was incorrect (glyph ids 54 162 163 164 165 166 167) (font-family: "via_expert" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0) source: data:application/font-woff;charset=utf8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAGWAABMAAAAAtywAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABGRlRNAAABqAAAABwAAAAc … gHlQsIDWTqENWKlCB2ivFLpAZ6nQA7rxD4JsVe/jtbOmrLX8CDpgP2G6oHNkeqC7ZvqgN2cGoD9jhmBwYw7AcMqMwMGdOQSjCXMEDuWfFYXyA25DYf4AAVGQiCoAAA==
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 print.css
Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content. markup.js:250:53
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 svg-sprite.svg
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 dsb-bg_1600x800.jpg
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 tokens
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 dsb-plus_440x280.jpg
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 alloweddates
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 pendlertjek_440x280.jpg
Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content. markup.js:250:53
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 dsb-logo.2014_pos_rgb.png
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 favicon-196x196.png
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 favicon-32x32.png
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 ciamsignedin
Cookie “.ASPXANONYMOUS” rejected because it has the “SameSite=None” attribute but is missing the “secure” attribute. 2 curtain
Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: https://www.dsb.dk/html/dist/js/nddk-requirejs/app.js?version=b6.0.656.11
Source Map URL: underscore-umd.js.map;

My Firefox cookie options are set like this:

I've tried disabling tracking protection for dsb.dk and added it to the exceptions list:

What other solutions could I try?
131.0.3 (64-bit) on MacOS Monterey
Feel welcome to edit the title if you know what specific error causes this, to make searchable for others.

Using Firefox 131.0.2, with many extensions active (e.g., uBlock Origin, Privacy badger), not allowing cookies, and from thousands of km outside Denmark, I was able to select København H to Aarhus H tickets. What version Firefox, and on what operating system, are you using?

@DrMoishePippik 131.0.3 (64-bit) on MacOS Monterey
